# How to register with extra credentials in flutter/firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am totally new to flutter and firebase and i saw some videos of signup and login but i noticed that everyone uses this method `_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: null, password: null)` to create new registration, however I want to register a user along with their other information such as address, contact etc. Is it possible, if yes how? any kind of video will be useful

Comment: You'll have to store the Extra details in a Database like `Firestore`

Answer (score 1):

`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: null, password: null)` this will create an authenticated user in the firebase console. If you want to add extra information, then you need to add that information to the database, example:

```
    firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) {
      dbRef.child(result.user.uid).set({
        "email": emailController.text,
        "age": ageController.text,
        "name": nameController.text
      }).then((res) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: result.user.uid)),
        );
      });
```

Here we add `age`, `email`, and `name` to firebase realtime database.